# How to set bashrc to check a command before execution?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to set .bashrc to check a specified command and ask for confirmation before execution.

For example, I want to set command 'rm' in .bashrc to receive a question before execution started otherwise being terminated.

```
read -p "Type password? " pass
if [ "$pass" = "1234" ]; then
  // do the execution
else
  // Termination and echo a message wrong pass. 
fi
```

**Example:**

```
> rm MyFile.txt
 Type password? ****
You have successfully removed MyFile.txt
>
```

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an alias or a function which will take precedence over the binary looked up from `$PATH` when resolving `rm` :

```
rm() {
    read -p "Type password? " pass
    if [ "$pass" = "1234" ]; then
         command rm "$@"
    else
         #Termination and echo a message wrong pass. 
    fi
}
```

Note that this doesn't constitute a reasonable security measure as it is very easily avoided by using `command rm`, `\rm` or the path to the `rm` binary (usually `/bin/rm`) instead of calling `rm`.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName that works for every command. Do you mean you want a single piece of code that will intercept every command, check if it's in a list then conditionnally execute some code?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is what he wants. Adding 8 lines for every command is not an elegant way to solve his problem. I mean, he may also do this by changing access rights of the executables, but he wants a nice .bashrc solution.

Comment: The code doesn't work. The error: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'.
Plus, it is fine if for every executable command e.g. (ls, rm, cd, ...etc) to write many lines of codes, but I just need it to work properly.

Comment: I couldn't edit the comment so I am adding a new one. The code works for rm() but not ls(). Can it be adapted to work for any shell command?

Comment: It works just fine for me with `ls`, maybe you have an alias defined for `ls`? What does `type ls` output in your modified environment?

Comment: @Aaron it didn't work because I used the same script for 'ls' which need to remove "$@" and it works. Am I right?

Comment: `"$@"` refers to the arguments passed to the function, so I expect without it `ls` will work as intended but `ls /path/to/dir` will target your current dir rather than the one passed as argument. I don't see how it could make the script fail, you might want to check what happens with `set -x`/`bash -x`

Comment: In that case, I will add a statement if arg is exist then `ls` + `"$@"`

Comment: @jesy2013 that shouldn't be necessary, and I'm afraid you'll encounter the same error anyway. Try defining `ls() { echo foo; command ls "$@"; }` in your shell and then calling `ls` and `ls /path/to/dir`, both should work fine. If you've got an error when declaring the function, it likely means you've already got an alias for `ls`